# PV operation points due to load changes

Tags: resistors, solar-cell, load, solar-energy, iv-curve

I couldn't find anywhere what happens to the operation point of a PV cell, when, a resistance (load) connected straight up its output, changes (step) from one value to another. With other words, suppose A is the operation point under load R1 and B is the operation point under load R2. When we step change the load (from R1 to R2), how will the point A will eventually move to the point B?  [image]

Answer (score 1):

The load line (or red line) will 'rotate' from A to B. A resistive load line always has a center around the 0V,0A point of the graph and has a slope according to it's resistance. While it's doing that the loading point will follow the blue curve.